# How to create nested html table in c# using recursion logic?

Tags: c#

I just tried over it but i got the HTML tables in the manner of unique,i just need the tables to created one within another.

sample output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/drdXx.jpg][1]sample

In Design Page

```
<table id="tableContent" border="1" runat="server"></table>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var s = 0;          
        Addtable(s);
}

public void Addtable(int j)
{
   HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
   HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
   cell.InnerText = "col 1";
   row.Cells.Add(cell);

   cell = new HtmlTableCell();
   cell.InnerText = "col2";
   row.Cells.Add(cell);

   tableContent.Rows.Add(row);

   tableContent.Border =1;

   if( j < 5)
   {
       j++;
       Addtable(j);

   }   
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Please decribe the desired and actual behaviour in more detail.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/drdXx.jpg][1]sample, please refer sample output.

Comment: @katherdx - Stack Overflow only works because people offer their spare time to help. If you post a question it is up to you to do as much work as you can to make it easy for us to answer your question. It is generally not acceptable to say "please refer sample output". You should make sure your question is clearly stated and you should adequately respond to all requests for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your recursion function as below

```
public void Addtable(HtmlTable baseTable, int j)
{
    HtmlTable innerTable = new HtmlTable();
    // change to stylesheet instead. Just added as an example to get the output
    baseTable.Style.Add("margin-left", "25px");
    baseTable.Style.Add("margin-right", "25px");
    baseTable.Style.Add("margin-bottom", "25px");
    baseTable.Style.Add("text-align", "center");
    baseTable.Border = 1;

    //Create a container cell for inner table
    HtmlTableRow container = new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell containerCell = new HtmlTableCell();
    Literal l = new Literal();
    l.Text = "Table " + j;
    containerCell.Controls.Add(l);
    containerCell.Controls.Add(innerTable);
    containerCell.ColSpan = 2;
    container.Cells.Add(containerCell);
    baseTable.Rows.Add(container);
    if (j < 5)
    {
        j++;
        Addtable(innerTable, j);

    }
}
```

Then call the function

```
 var s = 0;
 Addtable(tableContent,s);
```

Comment: @katherdx: Don't forget to accept the above answer.